# Signing kernel-mode Windows 10 driver

Tags: windows, driver, code-signing

I've developed a kernel-mode driver for Windows 10. How should I properly sign it? I want my driver to be installable without enabling test-signed drivers installation after sign procedure.

Comment: Pay the certificate mafia and then follow the Microsoft guidelines and upload for signing on their site. A simple web search should give the details you need...

Comment: @Anders, I am also working on the same thing and as a part of the process, I have to test the display driver with Windows Hardware Lab Kit. One of the tests is crashing (something with a stack corruption in the test itself) and I can't find any solution. It makes me feel those tests nobody even uses. Do you have experience with it?

Comment: @Anders yes, I've found a method which requires testing the driver with HLK and uploading it for signing. And it is the only way to sign driver right now, isn't it? Also, should all the tests be passed or only some specific subset of them?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get signed Kernel-mode-drivers for Windows without the test-signed state, one option is to apply for participating in the [Windows Hardware Compatibility Program](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/design/compatibility/) - from which you can obtain an official certificate for Windows-[HLK (Hardware Lab Kit)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/test/hlk/) drivers.

Among the requirements for passing this, are the succesful tests of the HLK-Framework (with your driver-software under test).

Besides your/your company's personal/business, you'll also have to hand out your product's specifications (the one the driver is meant for) to Microsoft.
Here's a [blog of the Window's Hardware Certification](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-hardware-certification/bg-p/WindowsHardwareCertification) where you can login/register yourself and wh which takes care of the process.

In order to test with the HLK-Framework - you need to download [HLK-Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/test/hlk/user/hlk-studio).

After passing the tests you need to [publish the driver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/dashboard/publish-a-driver-to-windows-update) @ Windows-Update.